# What would be the Regex expression to get the first letter after a group of character and some integers?

Tags: regex

I have a string that the following structure:

ABCD123456EFGHIJ78 but sometimes it's missing a number or a character like:

ABC123456EFGHIJ78 or 
ABCD123456E or 
ABCD12345EFGHIJ78 
etc.

That's why I need regular expressions.

What I want to extract is the first letter of the third group, in this case 'E'.

I have the following regex:

```
(\D+)+(\d+)+(\D{1})\3
```

but I don't get the letter E.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/5GA6YQ/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for the example cases you provided.

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]+)(?:\d+)(.)
```

It assumes that the first group is only letters and that the second group is only digits.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a nice answer.

But for the records, your initial proposal was very close to work.  You just needed to say that the character matching the 3rd group can repeat several times by adding a star:

```
^(\D+)(\d+)(\D{1})\3*
```

The main weakness is that `\D` matches any char except digits, so also spaces. Making it more robust leads us to explicit the range of chars accepted:

```
^([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)([A-Za-z]{1})\3*
```

It's much better, but my favourite uses `\w` to match at the end of the pattern any non white character:

```
([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)([A-Za-z]{1})\w*
```